# What is meant by the following two lines?

Tags: prolog

```
adjacent(X, Y) :- X =:= Y+1.
adjacent(X, Y) :- X =:= Y-1.
```

What do these mean? I know what the operator `\=` means. Is it similar to that?

Comment: It means `adjacent(X, Y) :- abs(X-Y) =:= 1.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More complex predicates are defined as rules, such as the examples you have shown above. The `=:=` operator evaluates both arguments and compares the result.

So `adjacent(X, Y) :- X =:= Y+1` states that `adjacent(X, Y)` is true if X is equal to Y + 1 and false if this is not the case.

As there is also a rule `adjacent(X, Y) :- X =:= Y-1`, X can also be equal to Y - 1 for the rules to be true.

In summary, for the rules to be true, X must equal Y + 1 or Y - 1.

Sources:

1. https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/prolog/
2. http://rigaux.org/language-study/syntax-across-languages-per-language/Prolog.html